# php twitter api - How to get access token?

Tags: php, twitter, access-token

I am using this code to generate access token:

```
if(isset($_POST['login_tw'])) {

$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']); 

    if($request_token)  {
        $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['request_token'] = $token ;
        $_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        if($connection->http_code = 200) 
        {
                $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);

                header('Location: ' . $url); 

                $fp=fopen('config.php','w');
                fwrite($fp, '<?php 
                $acsstok = "' . $_SESSION['request_token'] . '";
                $scrtaccstok = "' . $_SESSION['request_token_secret'] . '";
                ?>');
                fclose($fp);                    

        }
```

But the generated token can't be used for anything, especially to get a list of other user followers.

And the access token format is not like the one that is generated from 'Application Management' page that have leading numbers like this:

`340708911-xVcFcjVjkdksfdrjhgjdfyhjdfhjdhdfkdjgkfvaJ`

But it have no leading numbers like this:

`xVcFcjVjkdksfdrjhgjdfyhjdfhjdhdfkdjgkfvaJ`

What's wrong with the code above and how should it be so I can use the generated access token in my app?

Can somebody here help me? I have spending 1 day to find the solution for that problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

For a Twitter user to become a user of your application, you must ask them for permission.

Once you have the `request_token`, you need to redirect the user to an authorization screen on Twitter where they can approve your application as described here: [Obtaining Access Tokens](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens).

After granting access to your application, the user will be redirected back to your application, specifically at the callback URL that you specified. On that page, you need capture the information Twitter sent to you (an `oauth_verifier` and the original `request_token`) and then send another request to Twitter to exchange the `request_token` for an `access_token`. With this `access_token`, similar to the one you mentioned (with the User ID prefix), you will be able to perform authenticated requests to the Twitter API.

Please check [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) if you would like to use existing third-party PHP libraries and simplify these authentication steps when integrating Twitter in your application.

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to show me in a detailed example about how to obtain access token using twitteroauth? Their documentation is confusing.

Comment: I haven't used [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) myself but Abraham Williams, the author of the library, created a [GitHub repository with an example in PHP](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth-example). You can also check [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) from Matt Harris, and [some corresponding examples](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples).